# Python - PyQt5 how to take file as a input?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

There is screenshot attached below:
So basically i want to take file as a input(i.e suffix_list.txt) instead of specifying file location inside the function and when i clicked action button i need execute a output inside QtTextEdit
I tried something but i can't get it. Please help me out. I'm new to PyQt5
Thanks
This is my gui code:

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-    
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.10
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(514, 381)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.text_output = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.text_output.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 10, 351, 271))
        self.text_output.setObjectName("text_output")
        self.btn_Action = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_Action.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 300, 75, 23))
        self.btn_Action.setObjectName("btn_Action")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 514, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menuFile = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuFile.setObjectName("menuFile")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.actionOpen_File = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionOpen_File.setObjectName("actionOpen_File")
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionOpen_File)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuFile.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.btn_Action.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Action"))
        self.menuFile.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "File"))
        self.actionOpen_File.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Open File"))


    def file_open(self):
        name, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open File', options=QtWidgets.QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog)
        file = open(name, 'r')
        with file:
            text = file.read()
            self.textEdit.setText(text)

   def suffix_remove(self): 
        suffix_list = []
        dictionary = {}
        lists = ['athletic','kitchenette','helpful','terrify']
        with open('suffix_list.txt') as f:
            for lines in f:
                lines = lines.rstrip()
                suffix_list.append(lines)
        for words in lists:
            for suffix in suffix_list:
                if words.endswith(suffix):
                    final_list = str.replace(words,suffix,'')
                    dictionary[words] = final_list
        return dictionary


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    ui.btn_Action.clicked.connect(lambda: 
    ui.text_output.append(str(ui.suffix_remove())))
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: *I tried something* – what did you try and in what way did it not work as you expected?

Comment: @mkrieger1 - I mean i tried the above mentioned code. If you understand my problem statement please help me

Comment: No, I don't understand and can't help you. You have written what you want to do (even if I don't fully understand this), but not *what happens instead* or if you get an error, or anything else.

Comment: Do you want do display the contents of a file in the large text box? What is supposed to be the difference between clicking "Open file" and clicking "Action"?

Comment: I notice that you have defined a function `file_open` but are not using it anywhere. That might be a hint.

Comment: @mkrieger1 - No i don't want to display the file content. So basically when i click on OpenFile i will take the suffix_list.txt file as a input and then clicking an action button will print out the result. AND if you have saw suffix_remove() function.Inside that function i had specified the directory of suffix_list.txt. So i just want to take file instead of specifying the directory location

Answer (score 0):

The two main problems you have are that you do not call your `file_open` method and you are supplying an instance of `Ui_MainWindow` to your file dialog when it needs to be an instance of `MainWindow`.  Here is how to fix this:

```
def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
    self.main_window = MainWindow
    # your code here
    self.actionOpen_File.triggered.connect(self.file_open)

def file_open(self):
    name, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog(self.main_window, 'Open File', options=QtWidgets.QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog)
    # your code here
```

There are, however, some problems outside the scope of this question in your code structure that will make this difficult to expand upon.

Comment: Did you add `self.main_window = MainWindow` to your `retranslateUi` method?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone < 
Here is my answer what i actually want to do.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-    
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.10
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(514, 381)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.text_output = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.text_output.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 10, 351, 271))
        self.text_output.setObjectName("text_output")
        self.btn_Action = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_Action.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 300, 75, 23))
        self.btn_Action.setObjectName("btn_Action")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 514, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menuFile = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuFile.setObjectName("menuFile")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.actionOpen_File = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionOpen_File.setObjectName("actionOpen_File")
        self.actionOpen_File.setShortcut('Ctrl+O')
        self.actionOpen_File.triggered.connect(self.file_open)
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionOpen_File)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuFile.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate

        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.btn_Action.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Action"))
        self.menuFile.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "File"))
        self.actionOpen_File.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Open File"))


    def file_open(self):
        name, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, 'Open File', options=QtWidgets.QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog)
        file = open(name, 'r')
        with file:
            text = file.read()
            self.text_output.setText(text)

    def suffix_remove(self): 
        suffix_list = []
        dictionary = {}
        lists = ['athletic','kitchenette','helpful','terrify']
        f = self.text_output.toPlainText()

        for lines in f:
                lines = lines.rstrip()
                suffix_list.append(lines)
        for words in lists:
            for suffix in suffix_list:
                if words.endswith(suffix):
                    final_list = str.replace(words,suffix,'')
                    dictionary[words] = final_list
        return dictionary           



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    ui.btn_Action.clicked.connect(lambda: ui.text_output.append(str(ui.suffix_remove())))
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```